# Can I run a python script from C plus plus?

Tags: python, c++

I made a basic C++ script that looks like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std:endl;
}
```

I complied this and named that complied file `pcpp`.

Next, I made a python script named `runcpp`. This looks like this.

```py
import os
com = 'sudo stdbuf -oL ./pcpp'
os.system(com)
```

Then, when I run this python script, I see the "Hello World!" message. However, now I want to do something totally opposite.

Let's assume I have a file name `ppy.py`. This has script like this.

```py
print("Hello World!")
```

Now, I want to print this by running C++ compiler. How should I do this?

Comment: C equivalents of Python os.system() include [system()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) and [popen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just intend to run a Python script from C/C++ you could simply use `system()` to execute the Python script like `system("./myscript.py")`, which will use the interpreter specified in the shebang. This means say you have the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("Hello!")
```

It will run the script using `/usr/bin/python3` as that is specified in the shebang. Using `system("python3 myscript.py")` will use `python3` in your shell's `PATH`.

Alternatively, if you want to execute Python code within your C++ program you can embed the Python interpreter into your program, see https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html.